# Change Data Type in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, a "Copy data" activity was created to copy a table from a CSV file to Synapse.  All columns in CSV file are of String type.  How do I change a String type to a different type before I autogenerate a table in synapse?

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you need transformations. Move this from Copy to a Data Flow so that you can utilize data type inference there or manually set the data types in the source or by casting in a Derived Column.